# How should I punch myself in the face?

Tags: waiting-in-line-3d

Is it better to punch when you're still reasonably awake, or wait until you're about to drop off to sleep? Or is there some other way to optimize the time I can stay awake for by punching myself in the face?

Or does it not matter at all?

Comment: I heard that if you tab out while the game is running, you don't get tired as quickly.

Comment: @RedRiderX Where on earth did you hear something like that?

Comment: Voting to close as primarily opinion based.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The relevant code for health growth & energy drain is here:

```
if ( health > 0 ) {
    game_time += delta / 1000;

    energy -= delta * energy_speed * Math.random() + ( Math.log( game_time ) * Math.LN2 / 100 );
    if ( energy < 0 ) energy = 0;

    health += delta * health_speed * Math.random();
    if ( health > 100 ) health = 100;
}
```

Since both `energy_speed` and `health_speed` are constant, you can see that health grows at a linear rate.  The code for a punch event is here:

```
energy = Math.min( 100, energy + punch_energy );
health -= punch_damage + punch_damage_random * Math.random();
```

Again, `punch_damage`, `punch_energy` and `punch_damage_random` are all constant.

Putting these two facts together, if your health is below 100, and your energy is above 0, then it makes no difference when you punch yourself in the face.

The question then becomes when is the optimal time for the first punch?  Ideally you want to time your first punch to bring your energy back to exactly 100, and since `punch_energy = 20` you want to time your punch to be when your energy hits 80.

[image: diagram for illustration]